# Is there data base of quadratic fields which have abelian Hilbert class field?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

I did not find it in LMFDB. However, I am looking for a Database; please feel free to navigate me to any paper, which might be helpful.
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: By abelian Hilbert class field, do you mean what is usually called "absolutely abelian", i.e. abelian over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: If so, it is easy to extract this data from standard lists. Your condition is just that the genus number equals the class number, and there is a simple formula for the genus number in terms of the number of prime divisors of the discriminant.

Comment: For what it's worth, if $L/K$ is the Hilbert class field of a quadratic field $K$, then $L/\mathbb{Q}$ is Galois and $Gal(L/\mathbb{Q}) \cong Gal(L/K) \rtimes \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ where the action of the $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is by sending $\sigma$ to $\sigma^{-1}$. This implies that $Gal(L/\mathbb{Q})$ is abelian if and only if the exponent of the class group of $K$ is $1$ or $2$.

Comment: @JeremyRouse, could you please suggest a reference for the result you stated.

Comment: This is proven in Cox's "Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$" when when $K$ is imaginary quadratic (pages 122-123 in the 1st edition, or page 110 in the 2nd edition). The case that $K$ is real quadratic can be handled by replacing the complex conjugation element with the generator of the inertia subgroup $I_{\mathfrak{p}}$ where $p$ is a prime that ramifies in $K/\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{L}$ above $p$.